# How to make a row the column names and split up a string into multiple rows

Tags: r

I wasn't sure how to word the title of the question so I tried my best. I will give an example of my data set. We can call the dataset `my_data`

```
tibble::tribble(
  ~Pathway, ~log_value, ~ratio, ~z_score,                ~molecules,
     "GHR",      "N/A",  "N/A",    "N/A", "CD40LG,TGFBR1,MYH9,MMP1",
    "TGFB",      "N/A",  "N/A",    "N/A", "ADAMTS8,PIK3R1,HRAS,SEM",
     "PKA",      "N/A",  "N/A",    "N/A", "PIK3CA,PDGFA,PIK3R1,SPH",
     "PKB",      "N/A",  "N/A",    "N/A", "MAST2,PIK3CA,TGFBR1,BAD",
     "PKC",      "N/A",  "N/A",    "N/A", "TGFBR1,AKAP9,CAMK2A,PHK"
  )
```

So what I want to do is make column 1 into one row and have it be the name for each row. I also want to split up column 5 into multiple rows. So this is what I am envisioning.

```
GHR TGFB PKA PKB PKC
CD40LG ADAMTS8 PIK3CA MAST2 TGFBR1
TGFBR1 PIK3R1 PDGFA PIK3CA AKAP9
MYH9 HRAS PIK3R1 TGFBR1 CAMK2A
MMP1 SEM SPH BAD PHK
```

So I really don't need columns 2,3 or 4 so I got rid of them using `my_data <- my_data[c(1,5)]` and I was getting rid of the commas between the names by using `my_data$molecules <- as.character(gsub(","," ",my_data$molecules))` there were giving my issues but maybe you don't need to use that. So I just want to make column 1 the row names and split up column 5 into multiple rows, but I am struggling to do this. Does anyone have any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use the `dput()` function to show (a subset of) your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use this -

```
df = df[, c(1, 5)]

## Split on comma and add to dataframe
tmp = strsplit(df$molecules, ",")
df = cbind(df[, -2], do.call(rbind, tmp))

## Transpose the dataframe
df = t(df)
rownames(df) = NULL
```

Comment: Why did you add the `n = length(unlist(strsplit(df$molecules, ",")))/nrow(df)`?

Comment: So that you know how many columns to add in `df[, ncol(df):(ncol(df)+n-1)]`. The `strsplit` splits the string into `n` different parts, each of which will become one column.

Comment: This limits the number of my rows though. When I run it on my data set, the max number of rows is 14. Some of the data strings in column 5 are 100s of molecules in length

Comment: I have made an edit. Removed the `n = length(unlist(strsplit(df$molecules, ",")))/nrow(df)` line and just done a `cbind`. Does this work better?

Answer (score 1):

Your data, parsed

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
      ~Pathway, ~log_value, ~ratio, ~z_score,                ~molecules,
         "GHR",      "N/A",  "N/A",    "N/A", "CD40LG,TGFBR1,MYH9,MMP1",
        "TGFB",      "N/A",  "N/A",    "N/A", "ADAMTS8,PIK3R1,HRAS,SEM",
         "PKA",      "N/A",  "N/A",    "N/A", "PIK3CA,PDGFA,PIK3R1,SPH",
         "PKB",      "N/A",  "N/A",    "N/A", "MAST2,PIK3CA,TGFBR1,BAD",
         "PKC",      "N/A",  "N/A",    "N/A", "TGFBR1,AKAP9,CAMK2A,PHK"
      )
```

Here's a solution with `dplyr` and `tidyr`

```
df %>% select(Pathway, molecules) %>% 
  separate_rows(molecules,sep=",") %>% 
  group_by(Pathway) %>% 
  mutate(id=1:n()) %>% 
  spread(key="Pathway", value="molecules") %>% 
  select(-id)

#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   GHR    PKA    PKB    PKC    TGFB   
#>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  
#> 1 CD40LG PIK3CA MAST2  TGFBR1 ADAMTS8
#> 2 TGFBR1 PDGFA  PIK3CA AKAP9  PIK3R1 
#> 3 MYH9   PIK3R1 TGFBR1 CAMK2A HRAS   
#> 4 MMP1   SPH    BAD    PHK    SEM
```

Here, we first `select` columns of interest, then split rows by comma. The next task is to re-cast the data from long to wide format. In order to do it, you will need a unique id to match rows. Once you `spread` the column, `id` can me removed

Answer (score 1):

```
 dat=read.table(strings=F,text="Pathway log_value ratio z_score molecules
  GHR N/A N/A N/A CD40LG,TGFBR1,MYH9,MMP1…
            TGFB N/A N/A N/A ADAMTS8,PIK3R1,HRAS,SEM…
            PKA N/A N/A N/A PIK3CA,PDGFA,PIK3R1,SPH…
            PKB N/A N/A N/A MAST2,PIK3CA,TGFBR1,BAD…
            PKC N/A N/A N/A TGFBR1,AKAP9,CAMK2A,PHK…",na.string="N/A",h=T)


 a = data.frame(t(read.table(text=dat$molecules,sep=",")),stringsAsFactors = F)

 setNames(a,dat$Pathway)

      GHR    TGFB    PKA    PKB    PKC
V1 CD40LG ADAMTS8 PIK3CA  MAST2 TGFBR1
V2 TGFBR1  PIK3R1  PDGFA PIK3CA  AKAP9
V3   MYH9    HRAS PIK3R1 TGFBR1 CAMK2A
V4  MMP1…    SEM…   SPH…   BAD…   PHK…
```